# Mongo searching for unknown field via Regex

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I am setting up a mongo db based on various excel worksheets. 
Each worksheet contains data about people.
But there is no harmonisation of the columns name, so I don't know the fields I am saving in the database.
Now I would like to search all the records having a field like 'email'. So I would like to fetch all the 'e-mails', 'emails', 'EMAILS', 'mails', 'mail', 'Mail', etc... kind of field.

So my questions are :

(1) How can we do a search in mongo when we don"t know the field we are looking for ?
I understood that on a query we can do a "/mail/" or a "/.*mail.*/" to make a regex expression, but there I still need to know the field on which to do this regex !

(2) how to do a case-insensitive query on this field ?

Comment: i am not sure it is useful to have a sample doc : the question applies to any db : how to search records having a field corresponding to a regex...

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: You cannot execute a query to match documents based on the names of keys. Keys in MongoDB are meant to be known quantities and not something that you query for or regard as part of the content of the document. I would advise putting in the effort to enumerate and normalize all of your disparate column names. It's a pain, but it will be worth it.

For the second: MongoDB doesn't have a proper "case-insensitive search". The underlying reason is because, when you take into account different languages and scripts, case-insensitive search is actually very hard and complicated and MongoDB hasn't implemented all the tools necessary to deal with it yet. Nevertheless, there are two commonly used ways around this limitations. You can store a secondary value of the field that has been case-normalized

```
{
    "flavor" : "cHoCOlatE",
    "flavor_lc" : "chocolate"
}
```

or you can use case-insensitive regex (which will only work nicely for ASCII)

```
db.collection.find({ "flavor" : /chocolate/i })
```

Comment: all these tricks to make things faisable seem to need a lot of redundancy :(